# Update object from list of objects without affecting original reference of object

Tags: java, android, arraylist, reference, clone

Scenario is, i have a list of objects like `ArrayList<MyObject>`. When i modify the member (item/Myobject) of the list, it make changes to original reference of selected object of list. How to handle this scenario so that original reference of 
 object (MyObject) remains the same.

Comment: Please try to show your problem with some code; as I really dont understand your explanations.

Comment: Make a copy? `new ArrayList<>( previousList )` creates a new `ArrayList` containing all the elements of `previousList`, but it's not the same list so any changes to the new list will not affect `previousList`

Comment: @Sunshinator `new ArrayList<>( previousList )` creates a new list instance but when the new list is instantiated, elements contained in refer to the same elements contained in `previousList` . So modifying one of these elements will be reflected in both lists.

Answer (score 2):

You may use the `clone()` method but it has some important limitations. So I don't advise to do it.
Another way would be to create a new instance of `MyObject` by copying the state from the original instance in the new created instance.

You could add a factory method in `MyObject` that takes a `MyObject` object as parameter :

```
public MyObject(String message){
     this.message = message;
}

public static MyObject copy(MyObject original){
     MyObject copy = new MyObject(original.getMessage());
     return copy;
}
```

And you could do something like that to copy the instance :

```
List<User> myObjects = new ArrayList<>();
myObjects.add(new MyObject("hello msg"));
MyObject copyObject = MyObject.copy(myObjects.get(0));
```

Now if you want to protect from the modification, the elements containing in a `List` of `MyObject`, I think that you should not expose the `List` to the class clients. If the client forgets to do the copy, your requirement is not respected.
So you could provide a custom `get()` method in the class that contains the `List` to return the copy of the `MyObject` that is requested.
It would produce a more reliable defensive copy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cloning to solve your problem,
Just make clone of the and then change into the original object, So old object reference will be available in clone object.

```
Student18 s1=new Student18(101,"amit");  

Student18 s2=(Student18)s1.clone();
```

now you can make changes in s1 and your old object data will be in s2.